# How to initialize a UIKeyboardType with a string?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitextfield, uikeyboardtype

I have a jsondata struct that is build from a JSON file that contains this :

```
{
  inputFieldTitle: "Total Cost",
  keyboardType: "numberPad"
}
```

In my code, how can I use the attribute keyboardType to initialize the UIKeyboardType enum in order to set the keyboard type on my TextField?

Normally we would do this to get a numberPad keyboard (SwiftUI) :

```
TextField(jsondata.inputFieldTitle) { ... }
  .keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

But in my scenario, I can't hardcode the keyboardType with .numberPad, I have to use what's specified in the jsondata, how can I use that value to set the keyboardType on the TextField? This obvisouly does not work because the UIKeyboardType is of type Int :

```
TextField(jsondata.inputFieldTitle) { ... }
  .keyboardType(UIKeyboardType(rawValue: jsondata.keyboardType))
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Why don’t you construct a function that converts your String into the required Int for the enum?

Comment: That could be a solution, but I was wondering if there's a simpler way?

Comment: You're using your own construct for the keyboard type, you need to convert that into the type that is required, the simplest way is to construct a function that performs the conversion, or you could do something like Asperi has suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can conform UIKeyboardType to Decodable and implement your own custom decoder method:

```
extension UIKeyboardType: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let rawValue = try container.decode(Int.self)
            guard let keyboardType = UIKeyboardType(rawValue: rawValue) else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "invalid UIKeyboardType rawValue: \(rawValue)")
            }
            self = keyboardType
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let string = try container.decode(String.self)
            guard let keyboardType = UIKeyboardType(string) else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "invalid UIKeyboardType string: \(string)")
            }
            self = keyboardType
        }
    }
    init?(_ string: String) {
        switch string {
        case "default":                 self = .default
        case "asciiCapable":            self = .asciiCapable
        case "numbersAndPunctuation":   self = .numbersAndPunctuation
        case "URL":                     self = .URL
        case "numberPad":               self = .numberPad
        case "phonePad":                self = .phonePad
        case "namePhonePad":            self = .namePhonePad
        case "emailAddress":            self = .emailAddress
        case "decimalPad":              self = .decimalPad
        case "twitter":                 self = .twitter
        case "webSearch":               self = .webSearch
        case "asciiCapableNumberPad":   self = .asciiCapableNumberPad
        case "alphabet":                self = .alphabet
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension UIKeyboardType: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var encoder = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        let string: String
        switch self {
        case .default:                 string = "default"
        case .asciiCapable:            string = "asciiCapable"
        case .numbersAndPunctuation:   string = "numbersAndPunctuation"
        case .URL:                     string = "URL"
        case .numberPad:               string = "numberPad"
        case .phonePad:                string = "phonePad"
        case .namePhonePad:            string = "namePhonePad"
        case .emailAddress:            string = "emailAddress"
        case .decimalPad:              string = "decimalPad"
        case .twitter:                 string = "twitter"
        case .webSearch:               string = "webSearch"
        case .asciiCapableNumberPad:   string = "asciiCapableNumberPad"
        }
        try encoder.encode(string)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension DataProtocol {
    var string: String? { String(bytes: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

---

---

Playground testing:

```
struct Test: Codable {
    let inputFieldTitle: String
    let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
}
```

---

```
let numberPadJSON = """
{
  "inputFieldTitle": "Total Cost",
  "keyboardType": "numberPad"
}
"""
```

---

```
do {
    let test = try JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: Data(numberPadJSON.utf8))
    print(test.keyboardType.rawValue)  // 4
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(test)
    print(encoded.string ?? "")  // {"inputFieldTitle":"Total Cost","keyboardType":"numberPad"}
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This is pretty neat, as my jsondata struct is Codable, so this solution works like magic.

Comment: I saw that you changed from Codable to Decodable. Why did you decide to make the change and what is the impacted effect? My struct is Codable, so the Codable solution was neat.

Comment: You can keep it Codable if you would like to. If you need to encode it just make sure to implement the encoding part as well to keep it consistent otherwise it will encode it as Int.

Answer (score 0):

`UIKeyboardType` is-a `Int`, so you cannot use `rawValue`, because your json value is string.

Here is possible solution

```
extension UIKeyboardType {
    static private let types = ["numberPad": numberPad]   // << extend to all supported
    init(_ value: String) {
        if let result = Self.types[value] {
            self = result
        } else {
            self = .default
        }
    }
}
```

and you can now use it as

```
TextField(jsondata.inputFieldTitle) { ... }
  .keyboardType(UIKeyboardType(jsondata.keyboardType))
//  .keyboardType(UIKeyboardType(jsondata.keyboardType ?? "")) // if optional
```

Comment: Why not simply `["numberPad": numberPad]`? `types` is already a static property of `UIKeyboardType`. `Self.` is redundant.